# How to Create a Contour Plot on a Surface of a Unit Sphere from a Table of Values? [SOLVED]

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I've generated a table of the form

tupleListImport = {{theta_1, phi_1, value_1},{theta_2, phi_2, value_2},{theta_3, phi_3, value_3},.....,{theta_n, phi_n, value_n}},

where:

theta is a polar angle (in degrees) and ranges from 0 to 180 degrees, and

phi is an azimuthal angle (also in degrees) and ranges from 0 to 360 degrees, and

value is a number ranging between 0 and 1.

For your convenience, you can find the Table evaluated in steps of 10 degree in both the polar and azimuthal angles on my one drive [tupleListImport](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AhwPauxUumW3i2jcI7VtjqpIqCgE?e=zE2cnc).

When I plot tupleListImport using ListPlot3D and ListContourPlot, that is,

```
p1 = ListPlot3D[tupleListImport, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
   AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(2\)]\)", 
     "con01"}, {PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, White, Medium], ImageSize -> 400];

p2 = ListContourPlot[tupleListImport, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
    FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)", 
      Medium, Bold, White], 
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(2\)]\)", Medium, Bold, 
      White]}, {PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, White, Medium], ImageSize -> 400, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, ContourLabels -> All, 
   ContourStyle -> {Magenta, Dashed}, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
```

the plots (when evaluated in 1 degree steps) look like

[image]

What I would like to do is map the contour plots on a unit sphere using the same colour function, i.e., (ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors") so that the final plot looks something like this that I found on the internet.

[image]

I have made an attempt to generate this plot using the following code

```
(*Extracting individual lists of angles and values*)
thetaListDegrees = tupleListImport[[All, 1]];
phiListDegrees = tupleListImport[[All, 2]];
conList = tupleListImport[[All, 3]];

(*Convert degrees to radians*)
thetaList = thetaListDegrees Degree;
phiList = phiListDegrees Degree;

(*Define a function for the color based on con*)
colorFunction[con_] := ColorData["SunsetColors"][con]

(*Mapping the values to the sphere*)
points = N[
   Table[{Sin[theta] Cos[phi], Sin[theta] Sin[phi], 
     Cos[theta]}, {theta, thetaList}, {phi, phiList}], 4];

(*Flatten the points and conList for VertexColors*)
flattenedPoints = Flatten[Most /@ points, 1];
flattenedConList = Flatten[conList];

(*Create a SphericalPlot3D with colored points on the sphere*)
SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Small], AbsolutePointSize[8]], 
 MeshShading -> colorFunction /@ flattenedConList, PlotStyle -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ViewPoint -> {2, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

which generates (using steps of 10 degrees) a surface plot that looks like this

[image]

But this surface plot does not look consistent with the variation in colour compared to the contour plot above.

Also, the code freezes up if I attempt to generate a contour surface plot if I use 1 degree steps. I have run out of ideas on how to fix my code so that I accurately map the contours plot generated using ListContourPlot onto the surface of a unit sphere and how I can fix my code so that I can map any table with arbitrary polar or azimuthal angle step sizes. Any suggestion would be most welcome.

Thank you if you have gotten this far. :)

Comment: What is the function you used to generate `tupleListImport`?

Comment: Is it some kind of orbital?

Comment: It's a test function that I'm using to work out how to generate the surface contour map on a unit sphere.

Comment: There is function `SliceContourPlot3D` that can do that, but you would need the function to be defined in cartesian coordinates. Can you define your function in the form `f(x,y,z)=0` instead of spherical coordinates?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it like that. I think it has to be done using tupleListImport some how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`data` in my code is yours `tupleListImport`.

It seems that the plots match to each other.

```
data={{0,0,1.000},{0,10,0.9397},{0,20,0.7660},{0,30,0.5000},{0,40,0.1736},{0,50,0.1736},{0,60,0.5000},{0,70,0.7660},{0,80,0.9397},{0,90,1.000},{0,100,0.9397},{0,110,0.7660},{0,120,0.5000},{0,130,0.1736},{0,140,0.1736},{0,150,0.5000},{0,160,0.7660},{0,170,0.9397},{0,180,1.000},{0,190,0.9397},{0,200,0.7660},{0,210,0.5000},{0,220,0.1736},{0,230,0.1736},{0,240,0.5000},{0,250,0.7660},{0,260,0.9397},{0,270,1.000},{0,280,0.9397},{0,290,0.7660},{0,300,0.5000},{0,310,0.1736},{0,320,0.1736},{0,330,0.5000},{0,340,0.7660},{0,350,0.9397},{0,360,1.000},{10,0,0.9998},{10,10,0.9395},{10,20,0.7659},{10,30,0.4999},{10,40,0.1736},{10,50,0.1736},{10,60,0.4999},{10,70,0.7659},{10,80,0.9395},{10,90,0.9998},{10,100,0.9395},{10,110,0.7659},{10,120,0.4999},{10,130,0.1736},{10,140,0.1736},{10,150,0.4999},{10,160,0.7659},{10,170,0.9395},{10,180,0.9998},{10,190,0.9395},{10,200,0.7659},{10,210,0.4999},{10,220,0.1736},{10,230,0.1736},{10,240,0.4999},{10,250,0.7659},{10,260,0.9395},{10,270,0.9998},{10,280,0.9395},{10,290,0.7659},{10,300,0.4999},{10,310,0.1736},{10,320,0.1736},{10,330,0.4999},{10,340,0.7659},{10,350,0.9395},{10,360,0.9998},{20,0,0.9962},{20,10,0.9361},{20,20,0.7631},{20,30,0.4981},{20,40,0.1729},{20,50,0.1729},{20,60,0.4981},{20,70,0.7631},{20,80,0.9361},{20,90,0.9962},{20,100,0.9361},{20,110,0.7631},{20,120,0.4981},{20,130,0.1729},{20,140,0.1729},{20,150,0.4981},{20,160,0.7631},{20,170,0.9361},{20,180,0.9962},{20,190,0.9361},{20,200,0.7631},{20,210,0.4981},{20,220,0.1729},{20,230,0.1729},{20,240,0.4981},{20,250,0.7631},{20,260,0.9361},{20,270,0.9962},{20,280,0.9361},{20,290,0.7631},{20,300,0.4981},{20,310,0.1729},{20,320,0.1729},{20,330,0.4981},{20,340,0.7631},{20,350,0.9361},{20,360,0.9962},{30,0,0.9803},{30,10,0.9211},{30,20,0.7508},{30,30,0.4898},{30,40,0.1697},{30,50,0.1697},{30,60,0.4898},{30,70,0.7508},{30,80,0.9211},{30,90,0.9803},{30,100,0.9211},{30,110,0.7508},{30,120,0.4898},{30,130,0.1697},{30,140,0.1697},{30,150,0.4898},{30,160,0.7508},{30,170,0.9211},{30,180,0.9803},{30,190,0.9211},{30,200,0.7508},{30,210,0.4898},{30,220,0.1697},{30,230,0.1697},{30,240,0.4898},{30,250,0.7508},{30,260,0.9211},{30,270,0.9803},{30,280,0.9211},{30,290,0.7508},{30,300,0.4898},{30,310,0.1697},{30,320,0.1697},{30,330,0.4898},{30,340,0.7508},{30,350,0.9211},{30,360,0.9803},{40,0,0.9361},{40,10,0.8794},{40,20,0.7163},{40,30,0.4664},{40,40,0.1598},{40,50,0.1598},{40,60,0.4664},{40,70,0.7163},{40,80,0.8794},{40,90,0.9361},{40,100,0.8794},{40,110,0.7163},{40,120,0.4664},{40,130,0.1598},{40,140,0.1598},{40,150,0.4664},{40,160,0.7163},{40,170,0.8794},{40,180,0.9361},{40,190,0.8794},{40,200,0.7163},{40,210,0.4664},{40,220,0.1598},{40,230,0.1598},{40,240,0.4664},{40,250,0.7163},{40,260,0.8794},{40,270,0.9361},{40,280,0.8794},{40,290,0.7163},{40,300,0.4664},{40,310,0.1598},{40,320,0.1598},{40,330,0.4664},{40,340,0.7163},{40,350,0.8794},{40,360,0.9361},{50,0,0.8418},{50,10,0.7903},{50,20,0.6421},{50,30,0.4149},{50,40,0.1361},{50,50,0.1361},{50,60,0.4149},{50,70,0.6421},{50,80,0.7903},{50,90,0.8418},{50,100,0.7903},{50,110,0.6421},{50,120,0.4149},{50,130,0.1361},{50,140,0.1361},{50,150,0.4149},{50,160,0.6421},{50,170,0.7903},{50,180,0.8418},{50,190,0.7903},{50,200,0.6421},{50,210,0.4149},{50,220,0.1361},{50,230,0.1361},{50,240,0.4149},{50,250,0.6421},{50,260,0.7903},{50,270,0.8418},{50,280,0.7903},{50,290,0.6421},{50,300,0.4149},{50,310,0.1361},{50,320,0.1361},{50,330,0.4149},{50,340,0.6421},{50,350,0.7903},{50,360,0.8418},{60,0,0.6765},{60,10,0.6337},{60,20,0.5106},{60,30,0.3219},{60,40,0.09022},{60,50,0.09022},{60,60,0.3219},{60,70,0.5106},{60,80,0.6337},{60,90,0.6765},{60,100,0.6337},{60,110,0.5106},{60,120,0.3219},{60,130,0.09022},{60,140,0.09022},{60,150,0.3219},{60,160,0.5106},{60,170,0.6337},{60,180,0.6765},{60,190,0.6337},{60,200,0.5106},{60,210,0.3219},{60,220,0.09022},{60,230,0.09022},{60,240,0.3219},{60,250,0.5106},{60,260,0.6337},{60,270,0.6765},{60,280,0.6337},{60,290,0.5106},{60,300,0.3219},{60,310,0.09022},{60,320,0.09022},{60,330,0.3219},{60,340,0.5106},{60,350,0.6337},{60,360,0.6765},{70,0,0.4340},{70,10,0.4037},{70,20,0.3162},{70,30,0.1820},{70,40,0.01681},{70,50,0.01681},{70,60,0.1820},{70,70,0.3162},{70,80,0.4037},{70,90,0.4340},{70,100,0.4037},{70,110,0.3162},{70,120,0.1820},{70,130,0.01681},{70,140,0.01681},{70,150,0.1820},{70,160,0.3162},{70,170,0.4037},{70,180,0.4340},{70,190,0.4037},{70,200,0.3162},{70,210,0.1820},{70,220,0.01681},{70,230,0.01681},{70,240,0.1820},{70,250,0.3162},{70,260,0.4037},{70,270,0.4340},{70,280,0.4037},{70,290,0.3162},{70,300,0.1820},{70,310,0.01681},{70,320,0.01681},{70,330,0.1820},{70,340,0.3162},{70,350,0.4037},{70,360,0.4340},{80,0,0.1373},{80,10,0.1218},{80,20,0.07700},{80,30,0.008029},{80,40,0},{80,50,0},{80,60,0.008029},{80,70,0.07700},{80,80,0.1218},{80,90,0.1373},{80,100,0.1218},{80,110,0.07700},{80,120,0.008029},{80,130,0},{80,140,0},{80,150,0.008029},{80,160,0.07700},{80,170,0.1218},{80,180,0.1373},{80,190,0.1218},{80,200,0.07700},{80,210,0.008029},{80,220,0},{80,230,0},{80,240,0.008029},{80,250,0.07700},{80,260,0.1218},{80,270,0.1373},{80,280,0.1218},{80,290,0.07700},{80,300,0.008029},{80,310,0},{80,320,0},{80,330,0.008029},{80,340,0.07700},{80,350,0.1218},{80,360,0.1373},{90,0,0},{90,10,0},{90,20,0},{90,30,0},{90,40,0},{90,50,0},{90,60,0},{90,70,0},{90,80,0},{90,90,0},{90,100,0},{90,110,0},{90,120,0},{90,130,0},{90,140,0},{90,150,0},{90,160,0},{90,170,0},{90,180,0},{90,190,0},{90,200,0},{90,210,0},{90,220,0},{90,230,0},{90,240,0},{90,250,0},{90,260,0},{90,270,0},{90,280,0},{90,290,0},{90,300,0},{90,310,0},{90,320,0},{90,330,0},{90,340,0},{90,350,0},{90,360,0},{100,0,0.05137},{100,10,0.03793},{100,20,0},{100,30,0},{100,40,0},{100,50,0},{100,60,0},{100,70,0},{100,80,0.03793},{100,90,0.05137},{100,100,0.03793},{100,110,0},{100,120,0},{100,130,0},{100,140,0},{100,150,0},{100,160,0},{100,170,0.03793},{100,180,0.05137},{100,190,0.03793},{100,200,0},{100,210,0},{100,220,0},{100,230,0},{100,240,0},{100,250,0},{100,260,0.03793},{100,270,0.05137},{100,280,0.03793},{100,290,0},{100,300,0},{100,310,0},{100,320,0},{100,330,0},{100,340,0},{100,350,0.03793},{100,360,0.05137},{110,0,0.2286},{110,10,0.2059},{110,20,0.1404},{110,30,0.03968},{110,40,0},{110,50,0},{110,60,0.03968},{110,70,0.1404},{110,80,0.2059},{110,90,0.2286},{110,100,0.2059},{110,110,0.1404},{110,120,0.03968},{110,130,0},{110,140,0},{110,150,0.03968},{110,160,0.1404},{110,170,0.2059},{110,180,0.2286},{110,190,0.2059},{110,200,0.1404},{110,210,0.03968},{110,220,0},{110,230,0},{110,240,0.03968},{110,250,0.1404},{110,260,0.2059},{110,270,0.2286},{110,280,0.2059},{110,290,0.1404},{110,300,0.03968},{110,310,0},{110,320,0},{110,330,0.03968},{110,340,0.1404},{110,350,0.2059},{110,360,0.2286},{120,0,0.3605},{120,10,0.3319},{120,20,0.2495},{120,30,0.1230},{120,40,0},{120,50,0},{120,60,0.1230},{120,70,0.2495},{120,80,0.3319},{120,90,0.3605},{120,100,0.3319},{120,110,0.2495},{120,120,0.1230},{120,130,0},{120,140,0},{120,150,0.1230},{120,160,0.2495},{120,170,0.3319},{120,180,0.3605},{120,190,0.3319},{120,200,0.2495},{120,210,0.1230},{120,220,0},{120,230,0},{120,240,0.1230},{120,250,0.2495},{120,260,0.3319},{120,270,0.3605},{120,280,0.3319},{120,290,0.2495},{120,300,0.1230},{120,310,0},{120,320,0},{120,330,0.1230},{120,340,0.2495},{120,350,0.3319},{120,360,0.3605},{130,0,0.4532},{130,10,0.4210},{130,20,0.3285},{130,30,0.1865},{130,40,0.01221},{130,50,0.01221},{130,60,0.1865},{130,70,0.3285},{130,80,0.4210},{130,90,0.4532},{130,100,0.4210},{130,110,0.3285},{130,120,0.1865},{130,130,0.01221},{130,140,0.01221},{130,150,0.1865},{130,160,0.3285},{130,170,0.4210},{130,180,0.4532},{130,190,0.4210},{130,200,0.3285},{130,210,0.1865},{130,220,0.01221},{130,230,0.01221},{130,240,0.1865},{130,250,0.3285},{130,260,0.4210},{130,270,0.4532},{130,280,0.4210},{130,290,0.3285},{130,300,0.1865},{130,310,0.01221},{130,320,0.01221},{130,330,0.1865},{130,340,0.3285},{130,350,0.4210},{130,360,0.4532},{140,0,0.5158},{140,10,0.4817},{140,20,0.3833},{140,30,0.2325},{140,40,0.04752},{140,50,0.04752},{140,60,0.2325},{140,70,0.3833},{140,80,0.4817},{140,90,0.5158},{140,100,0.4817},{140,110,0.3833},{140,120,0.2325},{140,130,0.04752},{140,140,0.04752},{140,150,0.2325},{140,160,0.3833},{140,170,0.4817},{140,180,0.5158},{140,190,0.4817},{140,200,0.3833},{140,210,0.2325},{140,220,0.04752},{140,230,0.04752},{140,240,0.2325},{140,250,0.3833},{140,260,0.4817},{140,270,0.5158},{140,280,0.4817},{140,290,0.3833},{140,300,0.2325},{140,310,0.04752},{140,320,0.04752},{140,330,0.2325},{140,340,0.3833},{140,350,0.4817},{140,360,0.5158},{150,0,0.5567},{150,10,0.5215},{150,20,0.4199},{150,30,0.2643},{150,40,0.07340},{150,50,0.07340},{150,60,0.2643},{150,70,0.4199},{150,80,0.5215},{150,90,0.5567},{150,100,0.5215},{150,110,0.4199},{150,120,0.2643},{150,130,0.07340},{150,140,0.07340},{150,150,0.2643},{150,160,0.4199},{150,170,0.5215},{150,180,0.5567},{150,190,0.5215},{150,200,0.4199},{150,210,0.2643},{150,220,0.07340},{150,230,0.07340},{150,240,0.2643},{150,250,0.4199},{150,260,0.5215},{150,270,0.5567},{150,280,0.5215},{150,290,0.4199},{150,300,0.2643},{150,310,0.07340},{150,320,0.07340},{150,330,0.2643},{150,340,0.4199},{150,350,0.5215},{150,360,0.5567},{160,0,0.5820},{160,10,0.5462},{160,20,0.4429},{160,30,0.2848},{160,40,0.09086},{160,50,0.09086},{160,60,0.2848},{160,70,0.4429},{160,80,0.5462},{160,90,0.5820},{160,100,0.5462},{160,110,0.4429},{160,120,0.2848},{160,130,0.09086},{160,140,0.09086},{160,150,0.2848},{160,160,0.4429},{160,170,0.5462},{160,180,0.5820},{160,190,0.5462},{160,200,0.4429},{160,210,0.2848},{160,220,0.09086},{160,230,0.09086},{160,240,0.2848},{160,250,0.4429},{160,260,0.5462},{160,270,0.5820},{160,280,0.5462},{160,290,0.4429},{160,300,0.2848},{160,310,0.09086},{160,320,0.09086},{160,330,0.2848},{160,340,0.4429},{160,350,0.5462},{160,360,0.5820},{170,0,0.5957},{170,10,0.5596},{170,20,0.4556},{170,30,0.2963},{170,40,0.1009},{170,50,0.1009},{170,60,0.2963},{170,70,0.4556},{170,80,0.5596},{170,90,0.5957},{170,100,0.5596},{170,110,0.4556},{170,120,0.2963},{170,130,0.1009},{170,140,0.1009},{170,150,0.2963},{170,160,0.4556},{170,170,0.5596},{170,180,0.5957},{170,190,0.5596},{170,200,0.4556},{170,210,0.2963},{170,220,0.1009},{170,230,0.1009},{170,240,0.2963},{170,250,0.4556},{170,260,0.5596},{170,270,0.5957},{170,280,0.5596},{170,290,0.4556},{170,300,0.2963},{170,310,0.1009},{170,320,0.1009},{170,330,0.2963},{170,340,0.4556},{170,350,0.5596},{170,360,0.5957},{180,0,0.6000},{180,10,0.5638},{180,20,0.4596},{180,30,0.3000},{180,40,0.1042},{180,50,0.1042},{180,60,0.3000},{180,70,0.4596},{180,80,0.5638},{180,90,0.6000},{180,100,0.5638},{180,110,0.4596},{180,120,0.3000},{180,130,0.1042},{180,140,0.1042},{180,150,0.3000},{180,160,0.4596},{180,170,0.5638},{180,180,0.6000},{180,190,0.5638},{180,200,0.4596},{180,210,0.3000},{180,220,0.1042},{180,230,0.1042},{180,240,0.3000},{180,250,0.4596},{180,260,0.5638},{180,270,0.6000},{180,280,0.5638},{180,290,0.4596},{180,300,0.3000},{180,310,0.1042},{180,320,0.1042},{180,330,0.3000},{180,340,0.4596},{180,350,0.5638},{180,360,0.6000}};
```

---

```
interpf = 
  Interpolation[{{#[[1]] Degree, #[[2]] Degree}, #[[3]]} & /@ data];

SphericalPlot3D[interpf[x, y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50]

SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors", "ColorFunction"][
     interpf[#4, #5]] &), Mesh -> 10, 
 MeshFunctions -> {interpf[#4, #5] &}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are a freaking legend, azerbajdzan!! Thank you so very much! Can I ask one more thing, please? Is there a way to include contour lines similar to what you see in ListContourPlot? If I'm asking too much then never mind. You have been such a great help!.

Comment: I edited my answer with adjusted mesh to be consistent with coloring...

Comment: Thank you ever so much! That's just great. You have really made someone's day!

Comment: +1 great thinking using the data itself to create an interpolated color function! That opens up a nice avenue of new ideas. Nice work. Thanks for sharing this solution! Certainly worth an accepted answer from @QuantumKid unless an even better answer appears soon ;)

Comment: @azerbajdzan Sorry for the newbie question but what do the slot designators #4 and #5 refer to when you reference interpf[#4,#5] for ColorFunction and MeshFunction?

Comment: @jmm: Slots `{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6}` correspond to `{x, y, z, θ, φ, r}`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Aha. Thanks!